# Change on footer, multiple pages with jQuery

Tags: jquery, footer

Is it possible to make a style change to say an -tag in a footer that is copied to multiple html-pages and keep that style change when browsing between the different pages? Or does it have to be .php to do this?

Cheers.

Comment: You need to structure questions like "I have this code.... I want to do this.... I have this problem...."  This site is for coding issues, not discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u are looking for sth like a [jquery stylesheet switcher](http://www.cssnewbie.com/simple-jquery-stylesheet-switcher/). Yes thats possible! U can store the choosen style with [cookies](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

Comment: Ok so I don't feel quite sure how to target a .css value, or jQuery element with the jQuery .cookie. How would this work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie with javaScript : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp